# Examples of spaces where the Sobolev spaces are relatively compact in

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, reference-request, compactness, sobolev-spaces

*Background:* I work on a problem that deals with Sobolev spaces $H^s(\mathbb{R})$ of $L^2$-type. In my case $s$ is integer and $s\geq 3$. In order to evaluate some limits I need to show precompactness (or reletively compactness). The most simple definitions of precompact sets I know are:

**Definition 1:** A subset F of a space X is *precompact* in X if the closure of F is compact.

**Definition 2:** A subset F of a space X is *precompact* in X if every sequence in F has a subsequence that converge in X.

**My question is:**  In the definitions above, if $F\equiv H^s(\mathbb{R})$, what could be the space X, i.e. what would be the example of a space where the $H^s(\mathbb{R})$ space is precompact in?

Instead of $\mathbb{R}$ it could be any of its subsets. And examples of compactness and weakly precompactness would be very useful to know also (if anyone knows them).

**What I have found so far:** in the book **Robert Adams, John Fournier, Sobolev spaces, 2003**, I found only precompactness that deals with the $L^p$ spaces but not $H^s$. Only exception was on the page 179 where it stands:"Any bounded set S in $W^{m,p}_0 (\Omega)$ is precompact in $L^p(\Omega)$". Also I know that many Sobolev spaces are reflexive, and by the Alaoglu's theorem any bounded subsets are weakly precompact.

Just to note that the possibilities for the space X that would go well with the problem I am working on, would be some subsets of the spaces $BV$,  $\mathcal{M}$, $L^p$ for $p<\infty$, $\mathcal{D}^{,}$.

If you have any ideas or know any good reference in the literature about this, share it because I need help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @cmk: I know the Rellich–Kondrachov theorem. As I recall it deals with the embedding of Sobolev spaces into the Lebesgue spaces. And it that case it is usually $s\leq \frac{1}{2}$ by the Sobolev embedding teorems (I am maybe mistaken here). Do you know any version of Rellich's theorem where the space $H^s(\mathbb{R})$ or $H^s(\Omega), Ω\in \mathbb{R}$ is compactly embedded in some $L^p$ space and $s>\frac{1}{2}$? Preferably $p=1$ or $p=\infty$?

Comment: @cmk: Rellich-Kondrachov theorem deal with $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}$ too. But only with $H^1$ spaces (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem). And it won't work here. Just take $p=2,n=1$. I need something that works with e.g. $H^{37}$.

Comment: @cmk: some $s$ is great too, but I need any $s$. Thanks

Comment: I am a little confused by the discussion in the comments here. First if $s' > s$ then $H^{s'} \hookrightarrow H^s$ so you can just compose the compact embedding $H^{\frac12} \hookrightarrow L^p$ for suitable $p$ with the embedding $H^s \hookrightarrow H^{\frac12}$ to get a compact embedding of $H^{s}$ into $L^p$ for $s > \frac12$. This is really a weak statement as well. For $n < p$, $W^{k,p}$ embeds into suitable spaces of Holder continuous functions. See the second part of the sobolev embedding theorem [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Sobolev_embedding_theorem).

Comment: @RhysSteele. Thanks for the reminder on the Holder continuous spaces. But unfortunately those spaces are not adequate for the problem I am trying to solve. I am mostly interested in  the spaces such as $L^p$, $BV$ and similar. What would be the suitable $p$ in your comment?

Comment: @Mark That part of the comment was really to emphasize that making $s$ larger for $H^s$ makes things better and not worse! You get embedding in $L^p \cap C^\alpha$. You should think of $s$ as being a regularity parameter and so the larger it gets, the nicer the functions in $H^s$. Suitable $p$ is any $p$ for which  the embedding $H^{r} \hookrightarrow L^p$ is compact for $r \leq s$ with $r < \frac{1}{2}$. My last comment contains a proof of this fact, so you should check you understand and work out the range of $p$ this gives.

Comment: @RhysSteele, thanks for the follow up. Sorry for the late reply. Yes, the bigger $s$ the better. For the problem I work on, it would be the best if $p=1$ or $p=\infty$. I need to check if some other $p$ works too. $BV$ spaces would be great but as I recall there is no any big connection between $BV$ and $H^s$ spaces. Is there any connection between them that I do not know?

Comment: I'm not aware of one but I haven't had cause to work with BV spaces so it's possible there is one in the literature that I just haven't seen

Comment: In the current form, the answer is: Such a space cannot exist. A normed vector space is never compact (unless trivial). To get a non-trivial answer, you should restrict to bounded subsets of $H^s(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @MaoWao, thank you for the comment. I would be surprised if ti exists, but I am not an expert on the area, so that's way I wrote this question. I will try the bounded subsets of $H^s$ and also of $\mathcal{M}$. Some space of measures with weak topology would work good (I think).